# Rcpp Error: incompatible types (from %s to %s)

Tags: r, rcpp, incompatibletypeerror

I have recently begun using the Rcpp package to write some segments of my R code into C++.

Given a matrix of data, I have the following Rcpp function which calculates a kernel reweighted estimate of the covariance for some observation.

```
cppFunction('
        NumericVector get_cov_1obs(NumericMatrix cdata, int ID, float radius){

        int nrow = cdata.nrow(), ncol = cdata.ncol();
        float norm_ = 0;
        float w;
        NumericMatrix out(ncol, ncol);

        NumericMatrix outer_prod(ncol, ncol);

        for (int i=0; i<ncol;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<ncol;j++){
        out(i,j) = 0;
        outer_prod(i,j) = 0;
        }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<nrow;i++){
        w =  exp( -(i-ID)*(i-ID)/(2*radius));
        norm_ += w;
        for (int j=0; j<ncol;j++){
        for (int k=0;k<ncol;k++){
        outer_prod(j,k) = cdata(i,j) * cdata(i,k);
        }
        }

        for (int j=0; j<ncol;j++){
        for (int k=0;k<ncol;k++){
        out(j,k) += outer_prod(j,k)*w;
        }
        }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<ncol;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<ncol;j++){
        out(i,j) /= norm_;
        }
        }

        return out;
        }')
```

I would like to quickly estimated the kernel rewieghted covariance matricies for all observations in a dataset and store them as an array. Since Rcpp doesn't handle arrays I have written the following R function:

```
get_kern_cov_C = function(data, radius){
  # data is data for which we wish to estimate covariances
  # radius is the radius of the gaussian kernel

  # calculate covariances:
  kern_cov = array(0, c(ncol(data),ncol(data),nrow(data))) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    kern_cov[,,i] = get_cov_1obs(cdata=data, ID = i-1, radius=radius)
  }
  return(kern_cov)
}
```

This seems to work fine (and much, MUCH faster than R) however the problem is that every now and then (seemingly at random) I get an error of the following form:

```
Error in kern_cov[, , i] = get_cov_1obs(cdata = data, ID = i - 1, radius = radius) : 
  incompatible types (from X to Y)
```

where **X** is either builtin or NULL and **Y** is double.

I roughly understand why this is happening (I am trying to place a builtin/NULL variable into a double) but I am not sure were in the code the bug is. I suspect this might be something related to memory management as it only occurs every now and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for NULL at the C(++) level too, and in this case probably should do that.

As to why it is occurring: I am afraid you will need to debug this.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the reply. I'm quite new to C, how would I go about testing for NULL?